# Python/SSL authentification

Tags: python, ssl, request

I am trying to connect to the Visa Direct API, but i am not passing the basic SSL certificate authetification, here is my code:

```
import requests             
headers = { 'Content-Type' : 'Application/json' }
url = 'https://sandbox.visa.com/rsrv_vpp/v1/acnl'

 payload = {"SystemsTraceAuditNumber":565690,
"RetrievalReferenceNumber":"505012455690",
"AcquiringBin":409999,
"AcquirerCountryCode":"840",
"PrimaryAccountNumber":"4895070000008881"}

r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), 
 cert =('/etc/ssl/certs/sandbox_cert.pem'), headers=headers,
 auth=('370df57a-a8aa-4446-a23e-44a0ef06ea09',
 '6023e518-c36c-47a8-b16e-c8a5b3a941ef'))
```

Ass you can see i am using request and passing the cert argument along with the API user and password info but i keep getting the error:

> requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

Answer (score 1):

I get a SSL error when I try to open https://sandbox.visa.com/rsrv_vpp/v1/acnl in Google Chrome.

The Visa Docs say

> 4. SSL Server Authentication
>
> The SSL server certificate installed on sandbox.visa.com servers is a
>   Visa issued self-signed certificate. Client applications need to add
>   the sandbox.visa.com SSL certificate to their local trust store to
>   prevent SSL Handshake errors at runtime.
>
> Ensure that your application that connects to the Visa Direct API is
>   configured (or built) to use the trusted certificate store as a trust
>   store, and not a key store.
>
> Verify that the application is configured to use the right password
>   associated with the trust store file.

It looks like you need to do do some SSL Authentication before you can connect to Visa.

Comment: do you have any source for this? the API says you need to present a pkcs12 certificate to their server to pass SSL auth im not sure how to do that in python

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know anything more about SSL authentication. I have no idea what a pkcs12 certificate is.